# Firebase rules: Chat blocks

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following firebase rules for my chat:

```
"chat_messages": {
        ".read": true,
            ".write": false,
          "$key": {
            ".read": true,
                    ".write": "!root.child('chat_blocks/'+newData.child('username').val()).exists()",
            ".validate": "newData.child('content').val().length >= 2"
          }
      },
```

if the username is listed in the chat_blocks node, write is set to **false**.

The problem is that it's impossible to delete messages when using the above rules.

Changing `.write` of chat_messages to `true` allows everyone to post, even if they are listed in the chat_blocks node.

Any ideas what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: do you want the blocked user to be able to delete messages or other users to be able to delete messages?

Comment: Other users should be able to remove messages.

Comment: Your rules work for me. As long as your json data has a username key with a value different to any listed in /chat_blocks it works. Tried it on the Firebase simulator at the path /chat_messages/1 - won't work at /chat_messages of course.

Comment: @bastien I'm not trying to insert a new messages. I'm trying to remove. insertion works. remove doesnt. I updated my question with an image of the simulator says that writing is denied at `chat_messages/$key`. No idea what i'm missing!

Comment: I understand that but if the simulator allows a write in Firebase it means addition update and deletions are all possible. Change the key from unbanned_user to username and use a value that is not a child of your /chat_blocks node. You are using unbanned_user so newData.child('username') does not exist. I would need to see your db structure.